# multiple columns in ALL clause

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Is it possible to multiple columns with ALL clause.
please provide some examples

i tried this correlated query on HR shema.

---

```
SELECT *
FROM   job_history j
WHERE  ( employee_id, job_id ) = ALL (SELECT employee_id, job_id
                                      FROM   employees e
                                      WHERE  e.employee_id = j.employee_id
                                             AND e.job_id = j.job_id)
```

---

it does not consider about inner query and where conditions.Instead of that it returns job_history table.

Lets assume the tables

### job_history

```
employee_id   job_id
-----------   ----------
102           IT_PROG,
101           AC_ACCOUNT
```

### employees

```
employee_id   job_id
-----------   ----------
102           IT_PROG,
```

So according to my knowledge the query should output only `102 IT_PROG,`
But its output is

```
employee_id   job_id
-----------   ----------
102           IT_PROG,
101           AC_ACCOUNT
```

thats the problem..

Comment: I have no idea if Oracle supports tuple comparisons but the `WHERE` clause in the sub query means the `= ALL` comparison will always be true.

Comment: what is the table the alias name 'j' refers?

Comment: I think it might be easier to get help if you show your table, the data and the expected results after your query run.

Comment: tables are too big to upload.any way i have attached description about tables.

Comment: DESC job_history
Name          Null     Type         
------------- -------- ------------ 
EMPLOYEE_ID   NOT NULL NUMBER(6)    
START_DATE    NOT NULL DATE         
END_DATE      NOT NULL DATE         
JOB_ID        NOT NULL VARCHAR2(10) 
DEPARTMENT_ID          NUMBER(4)

Comment: desc employees
Name           Null     Type         
-------------- -------- ------------ 
EMPLOYEE_ID    NOT NULL NUMBER(6)    
FIRST_NAME              VARCHAR2(20) 
LAST_NAME      NOT NULL VARCHAR2(25) 
EMAIL          NOT NULL VARCHAR2(25) 
PHONE_NUMBER            VARCHAR2(20) 
HIRE_DATE      NOT NULL DATE         
JOB_ID         NOT NULL VARCHAR2(10) 
SALARY                  NUMBER(8,2)  
COMMISSION_PCT          NUMBER(2,2)  
MANAGER_ID              NUMBER(6)    
DEPARTMENT_ID           NUMBER(4)

Comment: only employees table employee_id is primary key.job_history has no primary key.hope these details may help you.you guys better to try this on oracle 11g default HR schema.

Comment: A stated above your `WHERE ... = ALL ...` will always evaluate to `TRUE`. What are you trying to achieve by that query?

Comment: i have edited the question please refer it.thnx

Comment: why not just: `select * from job_history j, employees e where j.employee_id = e.employee_id;` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oracle optimizer changes ANY, ALL and SOME operators during run time with EXISTS / NOT EXISTS and shifts the filtering criteria inside the correlated query. I checked one example on one of the [site](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/all-any-some-comparison-conditions-in-sql.php)...

```
SELECT e1.empno, e1.sal
FROM   emp e1
WHERE  e1.sal > ALL (SELECT e2.sal
                     FROM   emp e2
                     WHERE  e2.deptno = 20);
```

is interpreted by the compiler as

```
SELECT e1.empno, e1.sal
FROM   emp e1
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT e2.sal
                   FROM emp e2
                   WHERE e2.deptno = 20
                   AND   e1.sal <= e2.sal)
```

Still not very sure but may be the query that you have provided is being interpreted as following:-

Original Query:

```
SELECT *
FROM   job_history j
WHERE  ( employee_id, job_id ) = ALL (SELECT employee_id, job_id
                                      FROM   employees e
                                      WHERE  e.employee_id = j.employee_id
                                             AND e.job_id = j.job_id)
```

Oracle Interpretation(just a guess work based on > ANY example)

```
SELECT *
FROM   job_history j
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT employee_id, job_id
                                      FROM   employees e
                                      WHERE  e.employee_id = j.employee_id
                                             AND e.job_id = j.job_id
                                             and e.employee_id != j.employee_id
                                             AND e.job_id != j.job_id)
```

But still there is long way to discover the actual interpretation by ALL, ANY and SOME.

Anyways, there clauses were used long before I guess before 8i and so, now a days they are considered as obsolete, although Oracle supports them but they have been taken over by analitical functions and other techniques of querying data.

Answer (score -1):

It must be like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM   job_history j
WHERE  ( employee_id, job_id ) =ANY (SELECT employee_id, job_id
                                      FROM   employees e
                                      WHERE  e.employee_id = j.employee_id
                                             AND e.job_id = j.job_id)
```

Opposite of `=ANY` is `<>ALL`.

`x =ANY (SELECT ...)` is equal to `x IN (SELECT ...)`,

`x <>ALL  (SELECT ...)` is equal to `x NOT IN  (SELECT ...)`

Then you may try this one:

```
SELECT *
FROM   job_history j
   JOIN employees e USING (employee_id, job_id)
```